# How to get correlation coefficients in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, encryption, correlation

In every paper i read about encryption they like to show the correlation coefficients of their encrypted image by showing 3 values:
Horizontal correlation coefficient .
vertical correlation coefficient. 
diagonal correlation coefficient .
 and they show these 3 values for  encrypted image and also for plain image(lena). 
My question is how to do this in matlab ? and if there is no matlab function for it , what are the equation they are using to get those 3 values ?

Table 2
Correlation coefficients of two adjacent pixels in two images
example:

```
           Plain-image        Ciphered image
Horizontal 0.92401               0.01589
Vertical   0.95612                 0.06538
Diagonal   0.92659                 0.03231
```

Any lead would be helpful , thanks

Comment: Can you link to definitions of these three correlations?

Comment: Could it be as simple as following this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you would like to perform a correlation analyis for pairs of pixels within a certain given image.

In principle I would go for the `cov` function: in your specific case, `cov` will retrieve a `[2*2]` symmetric matrix. The diagonal elements will represent your **horizontal** and **vertical** correlation coefficients, whereas the lower (upper) triangular elements will stay for the **diagonal** correlation coefficient.

I hope this will help you.