# Correlation coefficients in matlab

Tags: matlab

corrcoef(x,y) returns a matrix which gives the correlation coefficient between the ith and jth members, how do we get the correlation coefficient for the whole thing?

I read this post:
[How to get correlation coefficients in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095429/how-to-get-correlation-coefficients-in-matlab)
But that doesn't really explain everything or help me find the "big picture" correlation coefficient Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `big picture`? Please remember that correlation is between two things. You can't say that you want to correlation of e.g `X` only. `X` has to correlate to something. You can say that `X` is correlated to `Y` though.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are after but **[corr2](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html)** could be a possibility if you have got the Image Processing Toolbox.

Load some test images. I resize `lena` to get the same resolution as the other image. That is a prerequisite for `corr2`.

```
lena = imresize(imread('http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lenaTest3.jpg'),0.5);
cameraman = imread('http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~phao/CIP/Images/Cameraman.bmp');
```

Correlation between the same images give a correlation coefficient of 1.

```
C = corr2(lena,lena)
C =  1
```

Correlation between different images give a low coefficient

```
corr2(lena,cameraman)

ans =  0.15804
```

Comment: I figured out the problem, it returns matrix of correlations between (x,x) (x,y), (y,x) and (y,y,) So that's why it outputs 4 numbers!